# How to assign a value to several variable in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, variable-assignment

I want to assign a value to two variable.

```
dim a as integer=7
dim b as integer=1
a=b=4
```

but vb.net detects the second equal as operate and compares the value b and 4 then returns false while i want to become a=4 and b=4.
I must use this type of assignment in my code.
can i do for this purpose?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do it. (Unless something changed in the latest release of the language)

Comment: If you are looking for a one-liner try a=4 : b=4 or  a=4 : b=a

Comment: *"I must use this type of assignment in my code"* There is no "must" here. There is not even a good reason to write code like this in C#. Write `a = 4` and `b = 4`. The effect is identical. Cramming it on one line won't run any faster, it'll just be less readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want those silly types of shenanigans, then move on over to **C#**:

```
int a = 7;
int b = 1;
Console.WriteLine("a = " + a.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("b = " + b.ToString());

a = b = 4;
Console.WriteLine("a = " + a.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("b = " + b.ToString());
```

Resulting with:

```
a = 7
b = 1
a = 4
b = 4
```

VB.Net was designed with **readability** in mind, however, so they didn't include that type of feature into the language.

Comment: It may behove your answer to explain why a = b = c = d ... = 1 is less readable than a = 1; b = 1; c = 1; d = 1; ... = 1 and why the trade-off in writing more brittle code is worth it.